# how to handle click event for each picturebox created dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have created about 100 pictureBox dynamically and want to handle click event for each pictureBox. moreover the control for each pictureBox must be different. how can i solve this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why is the answer not "add a click handler to each pictureBox"?

Comment: i have used loop for about 100 times to create 100 picture box. and i need to know which picturebox i clicked. So i need a control that lets me know which picture box i have clicked..

Comment: The first parameter of the event handler will tell you which box.  It will be the PictureBox object.

Comment: thank you, but how can i use that parameter. Should i keep id for each picture box?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the information and what information you need

Comment: It really depends on just what you need to know about the PictureBox.  If you need to attach a piece of information to the PictureBox you can do so by setting its Tag property at the time you create it.

Comment: In the loop: `Picturebox pb = new Picturebox {..}; pb.MouseClick+=aCommonClickEvent`

Comment: i only need to write a separate number on a message box  for each click event on a Picturebox.

Comment: Than use @hoodaticus solution. Use the tag property to store the id

Comment: @hoodaticus i created the tag for each picturebox as {p.Tag = widt;} where widt is just a number. now how can i get the value of tag from event control function..

Comment: Cast the sender object to PictureBox

Comment: Assuming it's an int: (int)(((PictureBox)sender).Tag)

Comment: thankyou , problem is solved now...:)